# Find a nearly circular band of bright pixels in this image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is the problem I have: I have an image as shown below. I want to detect the circular region which I have marked with a red line for display here (that particular bright ring).

[image]

Initially, this is what I do for now: (MATLAB)

```
binaryImage = imdilate(binaryImage,strel('disk',5)); 
binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage, 'holes'); % Fill holes.
binaryImage = bwareaopen(binaryImage, 20000); % Remove small blobs.
binaryImage = imerode(binaryImage,strel('disk',300));
out = binaryImage;
img_display = immultiply(binaryImage,rgb2gray(J1));
figure, imshow(img_display);
```

[image]

The output seems to be cut on one of the parts of the object (for a different image as input, not the one displayed above). I want an output in such a way that it is symmetric (its not always a perfect circle, when it is rotated).

I want to strictly avoid im2bw since as soon as I binarize, I lose a lot of information about the shape.

This is what I was thinking of:

I can detect the outer most circular (almost circular) contour of the image (shown in yellow). From this, I can find out the centroid and maybe find a circle which has a radius of 50% (to locate the region shown in red). But this won't be exactly symmetric since the object is slightly tilted. How can I tackle this issue?

I have attached another image where object is slightly tilted [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjswp1yyxjwuyvh/A61r.png?dl=0)

Comment: The image on your dropbox doesn't match up with the image you are showing in your post.  Also, the code you wrote to threshold the circle, its output doesn't correspond to extracting out the centre of the wheel.  In fact, it's slightly rotated and is grayscale.  Do you do some sort of rotation after you threshold and extract out the object?  Can you provide that code as well?

Comment: Did you try using [imfindcircles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html)?

Comment: Also, is the image ever tilted by a significant amount?  If that's the case, then Rafael's suggestion of `imfindcircles` will not work because the circles would be visualized more like ellipses due to the homography of the shape with respect to the orientation of the camera.  `imfindcircles` assumes that the circles are quite "flat".

Comment: @rayryeng  Yes, I have tried imfindcircles, even by decreasing the "Sensitivity" parameter. It doesn't detect any circle in that area.

Also, I have posted a different image on dropbox (sorry forgot to mention that) for which the algorithm has to work too. The image which I have displayed seems to be fine (almost circular). The output obtained is considerably okay. The output I have displayed is for another image which would be tilted (about +/- 20 degrees).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try messing around with the `'log'` filter. The region you want is essentially low values of the 2nd order derivative (i.e. where the slope is decreasing), and you can detect these regions by using a log filter and finding negative values. Here's a very basic outline of what you can do, and then tweak it to your needs.

```
img = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('wheel.png')));
img = imresize(img, 0.25, 'bicubic');

filt_img = imfilter(img, fspecial('log',31,5));
bin_img = filt_img < 0;

subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(filt_img,[]);

% Get regionprops
rp = regionprops(bin_img,'EulerNumber','Eccentricity','Area','PixelIdxList','PixelList'); 
rp = rp([rp.EulerNumber] == 0 & [rp.Eccentricity] < 0.5 & [rp.Area] > 2000);

bin_img(:) = false;
bin_img(vertcat(rp.PixelIdxList)) = true;
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(bin_img,[]);

bin_img(:) = false;
bin_img(rp(1).PixelIdxList) = true;
bin_img = imfill(bin_img,'holes');

img_new = img;
img_new(~bin_img) = 0;

subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(img_new,[]);

bin_img(:) = false;
bin_img(rp(2).PixelIdxList) = true;
bin_img = imfill(bin_img,'holes');

img_new = img;
img_new(~bin_img) = 0;

subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(img_new,[]);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very nice use on the LoG filter!  You're gonna give me a run for my money in the image processing tag :)

Comment: @jucestain Whoa! Thanks a lot! This seems to do my job. I would first want to test it for the other images (which are tilted) and get back to you. Again, thanks a bunch!