# Detect a small pinhole on cylinder's surface

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have segmented only a bottle from captured image (RGBImg_Raw).  Next, I want to detect this small hole.  However, I am not able to proceed further.

[image]

I tried using `filt_img = imfilter(img, fspecial('log',31,5));` as suggested by *jucestain* in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433655/find-a-nearly-circular-band-of-bright-pixels-in-this-image) . But this too doesn't seem to work. I get a completely black image.

I also tried detecting Canny and Sobel image edges, with various threshold values but it's noisy.

`I2 = adapthisteq(GrayImg);
BW1 = edge(I2,'canny',0.05);
BW1 = edge(I2,'sobel',0.1);`

I expected to get a circle around that pinhole, so I can find connected components and detect that hole.

Any suggestions?

I am using MATLAB. Attachments are here on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cbi0svk9v9wt5aa/AAA-Rm64quqGwnA101n1ubZSa?dl=0).

Comment: image link is not opening, could you please attach an image without circle annotation it will be helpful for suggestion. Thank you

Comment: you can use this peak finder in the FEX http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder

Comment: @AnkitDixit , done =)

Comment: @bla : Thanks, I just tried it. Lots of false peaks detected. Plus there are no peaks detected near the pinhole.

Comment: @Meghana, good you found the solution.

Comment: well you need to set a threshold...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's using the [fast 2d peak finder](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder) from the FEX:

```
    % this part reads the image and gets rid of the white frame around it
    d=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSQLZ.png');
    d=rgb2gray(d);
    d(d==255)=0;


    % now peak finding with threshold as 0.8*max image intensity
    p=FastPeakFind(d,max(d(:))*0.8);
    figure;
    imagesc(d); hold on
    plot(p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'rx')

    % the peak is found at 
    p =

           735
           355
```

[image]

EDIT:

For the other image a flat threshold is not suitable. In order to make it work you need to apply a local threshold, or do something that is called "common mode correction" of your image. Some cameras produce imaging data that should not directly be used in analysis and need corrections. Most popular corrections are: dark rate (pedestal) subtraction, bad pixel masking, common mode correction, gain correction, etc. Without going into too many details (you can search more info about the above), you can do the following "computational" trick, taking the local mean of the image you want to analyze:

```
d=GrayImg;
% Read comments in the FEX of the 2d fast peak find, is all there 
ws=100; % window size
mean_d=imfilter(d,fspecial('average',ws),'replicate'); % this a local mean operation
dd=d-mean_d;
filt = (fspecial('gaussian', 7,1));  
p=FastPeakFind(dd,40,filt,600 );

imagesc(dd); hold on
plot(p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'wx');
```

[image]

So I've set edg to be 600 because I'm lazy. The best thing to do is to apply the above to a region of interest of the image, so you'll avoid the edges of the cylinder giving you false peaks.

Comment: bla, Thank you. Could you please try for `GrayImg 30` as well? I am not able to plot points for this image. (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cbi0svk9v9wt5aa/AAA-Rm64quqGwnA101n1ubZSa?dl=0)

Comment: There are many false points plotted. Any idea how I can handle this issue? I tried changing threshold. I used 0.95 for `GrayImg 30`. Works! Unfortunately, the same value doesn't detect any points in `GrayImg 30`

Comment: Meghana in both the images scale is not same so if you will use any algorithm thresholds will vary accordingly. try to keep scale of the images same if you can do.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code which is based on simple steps for segmentation:

```
        clc
        clear all
        close all

        im1 = imread('bottle.png');
        gray1 = (rgb2gray(im1));
        gray1 = imfilter(gray1,fspecial('gaussian',[5,5],1.5),'replicate');
        figure,imshow(im1,[])
        [~,~,mg,~] = ImageFeatures.Gradients(gray1); % Sobel is used here.
        mgBw = im2bw(mg,graythresh(mg));
        rg = regionprops(mgBw,'Area','PixelIdxList');

        minAreaObj = false(size(mgBw));
        for i = 1:length(rg)
            area = rg(i).Area;
            idx = rg(i).PixelIdxList;

            if area<1000
                minAreaObj(idx) = true;
            end

        end

        minAreaObj = imopen(minAreaObj,strel('disk',3));
```

Here are result of the algorithm:

[image]

[image]

Code for gradient:

```
  function [gx,gy,mag,phi] = Gradients(gray)
        gray = double(gray);
        horzmask = fspecial('sobel');
      %  vertmask = horzmask';

        gx = imfilter(gray,horzmask,'replicate');
        gy = imfilter(gray,horzmask','replicate');

        phi = (atan2((gy),(gx)));

        mag = mat2gray(sqrt(gx.^2+gy.^2));
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the line ` [~,~,mg,~] = ImageFeatures.Gradients(gray1); % Sobel is used here.`

I get an error stating: 


**Undefined variable "ImageFeatures" or class "ImageFeatures.Gradients" 

Error in Test2 (line 10) 
       [~,~,mg,~] = ImageFeatures.Gradients(gray1); % Sobel is used here.**

Comment: that is a customized function written by me for sobel gradient, but sad this algorithm is not working in the second image you have posted due to scale differences, difference in scales will always lead to varying nature of object characteristics. try to take images on the same scale if possible.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. But how can I use the customized algorithm? Are you sharing it?

Comment: its just filtering of image using sobel mask (imfilter(image,fspecial('sobel'),'replicate') in both the direction. and then simply find magnitude.

Comment: You should probably consider posting your code for `ImageFeatures.Gradients`.  StackOverflow answers are supposed to be verifiable, repeatable and stand alone by themselves.  If you're not willing to include this code in your post, at least a link to where to download it would suffice... like bla's post with his fast 2D peak finder.

Answer (score 1):

below a solution that works without additional functions but is based on the image processing toolbox

```
clear all
close all

rawimage  = imread('MSQLZ.png');
sumimage  = sum(rawimage,3);
bwlabelim = bwlabel(sumimage,8);
shapedata = regionprops ( bwlabelim,'all');
the_bottle = find([shapedata.MajorAxisLength] == min(shapedata.MajorAxisLength));
only_bottle = zeros(size(bwlabelim));
only_bottle(bwlabelim==the_bottle)= 1;
sumimage(~only_bottle)=0;
[y,x] = ind2sub(size(sumimage),find(sumimage==(max(max(sumimage)))));
contourf(sumimage,'LineColor','none')
hold on
plot(x,y,'ro')
```

it sums the RGB values and created a bwimage. From this one I extract the region properties and search for the one with the smallest diameter as this is your bottle. The I create a logical image to filter from your image the frame leaving only the bottle values. Within this I search for the maximum and extract the coordinates.

Comment: This is a simple and smart way, thanks! I'll look through it.

Answer (score -1):

```
im=imread('bottle.png');


im=im2bw(im,0.7);
imshow(im)
```

Comment: Well, I don't consider `im2bw` a very reliable option, especially with a fixed threshold. It has to work for other similar images as well!